# Cancel dropping a node in GRID in extjs

Tags: extjs

There is isValidDropPoint() in TreeDropZone from which if we return false then it will not drop that node (or goto beforenodedrop event)

I want to know what function is there in GRID from which if i return false then it will not drop that node (or goto notifyDrop event)

Thanks alot in advance
Regards

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this example by Saki: http://examples.extjs.eu/?ex=ddgrids

He defines a DropZone for the grid called Example.GridDropZone. If the onContainerOver function returns this.dropNotAllowed, the drop operation won't be allowed.

Comment: hi thanks for replying...but its not actually like that....if you see then you will realize that the condition dd.grid !== this.grid is being implemented in onContainerOver as well as onContainerDrop. It doesn't mean if we return false from onContainerOver then it wont go to onContainerDrop

Comment: Isn't there a way to cancel dropping node????? we need to check all conditions in onContainerOver and onContainerDrop also??????? really????